# Smooth Mesh obtained from sectioned image

Tags: objects, topology

I have meshes which were obtained by sectional imaging (i.e. CT scan), and due to that fact (or due to the way the stl is generated from the scan) it looks like the object is a number of stacked planes.

[image]

Is there an easy way to smooth out these artefacts? I have tried re-meshing and the different smooth modifiers but none of them had the desired effect.

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.